# C# WPF upload and save Image to file

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF application and I want to be able to Upload and save an image to a folder. I have the following code below but not sure how to save it after I upload and display the image.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Margin="12,12,16,71" Name="imgPhoto" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,34" Name="btnLoad" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Click="btnLoad_Click">
        _Load
    </Button>
    <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,34" Name="btnSave" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Grid.Column="2" Click="btnSave_Click">
        _Save
    </Button>
</Grid>



private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            imgPhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fd.FileName));
            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fd.FileName);
            stream = File.OpenRead(fd.FileName);
            byte[] binaryImage = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(binaryImage, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: See [File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and the opposite operation, `WriteAllBytes`.

Answer (score 4):

To show your image from a file loaded

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            imgPhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fd.FileName));    
        }
    }
```

To save loaded file, simply, copy it

```
    var fileNameToSave = DateTime.Now.ToFileNameFormat() + Path.GetExtension(fd.FileName);
    var imagePath = Path.Combine("C:\" + fileNameToSave);                
    File.Copy(fd.FileName, imagePath);
```